# select rows in sql with end_date >= start_date for each ID repeated multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

Attached the image how the data looks like. In my table I have 3 columns `id`, `start date`, and `end date`, and values like this:

```
id     start date  end date
-------------------------------
100    2015-01-01  2015-12-31
100    2016-01-10  2018-12-31
200    2015-02-15  2016-03-15
200    2016-03-15  2016-12-31
300    2016-01-01  2016-12-31
400    2017-01-01  2017-12-31
500    2017-02-01  2017-12-31
600    2017-01-15  2017-03-05
600    2017-02-01  2018-12-31
```

I want my output to be

```
id     start date  end date
--------------------------------
100    2015-01-01  2015-12-31
100    2016-01-10  2018-12-31
200    2015-02-15  2016-12-31
300    2016-01-01  2016-12-31
400    2017-01-01  2017-12-31
500    2017-02-01  2017-12-31
600    2017-01-15  2018-12-31
```

Query:

```
select 
    id, *
from 
    dbo.test_sl 
where 
    id in (select id
           from dbo.test_sl 
           where end_date >= start_date 
           group by id)
```

Please help me get the output I am looking for.

[image]

Comment: You want to combine two rows into a single one when the dates match. What happens if you have three or more rows that match that condition? Do you want to combine all three rows into a single one?

Comment: This is a common problem, *merge overlapping intervals/ranges*, e.g. see this article by Itzik Ben-Gan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of a gaps-and-islands problem.  In this case, you want to find adjacent rows that *do not* overlap for the same `id`.  These are the starts of groups.  A cumulative sum of the starts of a group providing a grouping number, which can be used for aggregation.

In a query, this looks like:

```
select id, min(startdate), max(enddate)
from (select t.*,
             sum(isstart) over (partition by id order by startdate) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   (case when exists (select 1
                                      from test_sl t2
                                      where t2.id = t.id and
                                            t2.startdate < t.startdate and
                                            t2.enddate >= t.startdate
                                     )
                         then 0 else 1
                     end) as isstart
            from test_sl t
           ) t
      ) t
group by id, grp;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that only two records can be combined together, you can `LEFT JOIN` the table with itself and then use a `CASE` to display the end date of the self-joined record, if available.

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    min(t1.start_date),
    CASE WHEN t2.end_date IS NULL THEN t1.end_date ELSE t2.end_date END
FROM
    table t1
    LEFT JOIN table t2 
        ON  t1.id = t2.id 
        AND t2.start_date > t1.start_date
        AND t2.start_date <= t1.end_date
GROUP BY 
    t1.id,
    CASE WHEN t2.end_date IS NULL THEN t1.end_date ELSE t2.end_date END
ORDER BY 1
```

Tested in [this SQL Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=185d6d93bd63df7b9a2f4c5b78d6e9f6)

Comment: i ran the query you provided. and i am getting 11 rows instead of 7 rows.
for id 200 and 600 i want to see my results like this.
200 2015-02-15  2016-12-31
600 2017-01-15  2018-12-31

Comment: id start_date end_date
100 2015-01-01 2015-12-31
100 2016-01-10 2018-12-31
200 2015-02-15 2016-03-15
200 2015-02-15 2016-12-31
200 2016-03-15 2016-12-31
300 2016-01-01 2016-12-31
400 2017-01-01 2017-12-31
500 2017-02-01 2017-12-31
600 2017-01-15 2017-03-05
600 2017-01-15 2018-12-31
600 2017-02-01 2018-12-31
This is the output from your query . i don't want 3 rows with 200 and 600.Need only 1 each row combined date together with 200 and 600

Comment: @swathi : fixed ! also added a link to a DB Fiddle that demonstrates the query

Comment: congratulations for such a nice answer.

Comment: @GMB : I am still not able to get what i am looking for.But thanks a lot for digging into this.
i am getting 2 records for ID 200 which i should only get one record with values
id start_date end_date
200 2015-02-15 2016-12-31
and i am getting 2 records for ID 600 which i should only get one record with values
id start_date end_date
600 2017-01-15 2018-12-31

Comment: I am getting this error:
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 35
Column 'dbo.test_sl.start_date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
when i add t1.start_date to group by i am getting 2 rows with ID 200 and 2 rows with ID 600

Comment: @swathi : sorry ! my answer was for mysql... I just updated the query and the fiddle for SQLServer - works fine for me now

Comment: Thanks @BarbarosÖzhan... feedback much appreciated !

Comment: @GMB: Don't be sorry .Thank you for trying this and helping me to resolve.
It works but if i have other row for ID= 600 like this
id (start_date) (end_date)
600 2017-02-01 2019-12-31
it is not working.  I need to get only 1 row for 600 ID with min(start_date) and Max(end_date).
Sorry for the trouble.Can you please try

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses a Recursive CTE.

It basically loops through the dates per id, and keeps the smallest start_date for the overlapping end_date/start_date.

Then the result is grouped so there are no more overlaps.

Test [here](https://rextester.com/TWQ52132) on rextester.

```
WITH SRC AS
(
  SELECT id, start_date, end_date, 
   row_number() over (partition by id order by start_date) as rn
  FROM test_sl
)
, RCTE AS
(
  SELECT id, rn, start_date, end_date
  FROM SRC
  WHERE rn = 1

  UNION ALL

  SELECT t.id, t.rn, iif(r.end_date >= t.start_date, r.start_date, t.start_date), t.end_date
  FROM RCTE r
  JOIN SRC t ON t.id = r.id AND t.rn = r.rn + 1
)
SELECT id, start_date, max(end_date) as end_date
FROM RCTE
GROUP BY id, start_date
ORDER BY id, start_date;
```